# How to add 'n' number of spaces between two Column names in Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a basic query which gives me FullName from columns FirstName & LastName

**Query:**

```
select StudentID,
    FirstName + ' ' + LastName as FullName
from Students
```

Now i am interested to see is there any chance we can add spaces between `FirstName` & `LastName` in query while joining dynamic ?

per say i need to have 50 spaces between `FirstName` & `LastName` ? Can i achieve this.

one solution would be adding spaces manually which does look the way to go here .

Comment: use [`REPLICATE(' ',50)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx)

Comment: great one ! @ughai thanks buddie . you can post it as answer so i can accept it . cheers

Comment: Well, I was almost 100% sure this question qualified as a dup. it looks like my SO search-foo is not as good as i thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`REPLICATE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx) allows to duplicate a specified string n number of times.

```
SELECT StudentID,
    FirstName + REPLICATE(' ',50) + LastName as FullName
FROM Students
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this:

```
right(replicate('0',10)+cast(@num as varchar(15)),10) aS lpad_number
```

Just replace the '0' with spaces I guess.

This is more useful:

```
left(field + replicate(' ',5),5)
```

You can go left or right of the column as you see fit.